# UI5 performance parameters: data-sap-ui-async vs. data-sap-ui-xx-nosync

Tags: sapui5

UI5 bootstrapper has two parameters, which are responsible for the way UI5 loads the libs:

- `data-sap-ui-async`
- `data-sap-ui-xx-nosync`

In a case of [**`data-sap-ui-async="true"`**](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/408b40efed3c416681e1bd8cdd8910d4) everything is clear:

> *The most important setting is `data-sap-ui-async="true"`. This enables the runtime to load all the modules and preload files for all declared libraries asynchronously, if an asynchronous API is used. Setting `async=true` leverages the browser's capabilities to execute multiple requests in parallel, without blocking the UI thread.*

I know that `data-sap-ui-xx-nosync="warn"` allows identifying synchronously loaded libs.

But what are the benefits of using `data-sap-ui-xx-nosync="true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Configuration Options and URL Parameters](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070), `data-sap-ui-xx-nosync="true"` thorws a `new Error` instead of a simple log.

> When set to `warn`, any use of synchronous XHRs will be reported with a warning in the console. When set to `true`, such calls will cause an error.

What happens with the [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) depends on the caller and the application code. In some cases, such errors can break the app. See [this plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/wcZOB53cXjvZbVP7) for example. With `true`, the custom JS file cannot be loaded.

> What are the benefits of using `data-sap-ui-xx-nosync="true"`?

Since `true` throws an actual error instance, you might want to react to such events with e.g. `window.addEventListener("error", fn)`. Might be useful for regression tests.